# How to Pass Knockout ahref value into jquery variable

Tags: php, jquery, knockout.js

> Knockout js Data

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: URLPath }" type="submit">Download</a>
```

> I get Value of "A tag" as www.ex.com/sp/file.zip

script

```
function DataItem(data) {
    this.URLPath = ko.observable(data.path); //www.ex.com/sp/file.zip
}
```

> jQuery Script

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
    $.post('fs.php', 'sp=' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
      -----------
      ----------- 
    });
});
```

I need `data-bind="attr: { href: URLPath }"` (www.ex.com/sp/file.zip) Value in jQuery Variable "SP="(www.ex.com/sp/file.zip) is that possible?

Comment: I am sorry, Your question is not clear for me, can you explain what actually you want to do?

Comment: i need data-bind=attr: '{ href: URLPath }' value into jquery variable

Comment: why not use the knockout submit binding instead. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

Comment: hmm its helpful but it will be more helpful if i get my answer as i suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
function DataItem(data) {
 this.URLPath = ko.observable(data.path); 
}

var mymodel = new DataItem(data);

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
 $("input[type=submit]").click(function (event) {
    $.post('fs.php', 'sp=' + mymodel.URLPath(), function (data) {
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: is that possible to pass <a data-bind=> value to jquery sorry for this questions but seriously don`t get any logic to solve this

Comment: You get this error, because, due to security reasons, the browser has no access to the local filesystem. Either use a webserver to serve the files or create a folder inside your application's folder and use relative paths.